# Integration with respect to total variation

Tags: measure-theory

Is it true that
$$ \int |f| \, d |\mu|  = \int |f|\chi_E \, d\mu - \int |f|\chi_F \, d\mu,$$
where $E$ and $F$ are the positive and negative sets from the Hahn decomposition?

Comment: what is $|\mu|$?

Comment: I think you should add them instead of subtract, since the total variation is a positive measure.